# Can I eat the corpses of my dead siblings?

Tags: tokyo-jungle

When you breed a new generation, it's possible to end up with more than one in a litter. These extras are considered packmates, which you can use to distract enemies or help you hunt. Is it possible, after losing one or more packmates after a big fight, to consume their corpses to gain calories and restore fullness?

Comment: Excellent question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no. When any of your siblings die, they can only be eaten by animals of another species. The corpses of your brethren can also become an obstacle if you are trying to flee from stronger animals. Stay wary of your surroundings when any deaths occur.